# Yii2 Restful. How can i receive data from 3 tables

Tags: yii2

I want to receive data like this:

> categories
>     ----category1
>     ----category2
>   topProducts
>     ----product1
>       --------photo1
>       --------photo2
>     ----product2
>       --------photo1
>       --------photo2

I need get all categories and top x products.
Each product has two photos.
How can i do this by using yii2 restful?
Thanks.

Comment: why are categories and products on the same level? do you need categories with top products or top products with categories?

Comment: @Thành Nguyễn Minh, have you tried solution posted by csminb? If he answered your question, you should mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

the query shold look something like this

```
Category::find()
    ->with(['subcategories','topProducts', 'topProducts.images'])
    ->all();
```

you can use joinWith if you absolutely want a single query

---

if you retrieve your data with an ActiveController, you need to specify [extraFields](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-arrayabletrait.html#extraFields()-detail) to the Category model. (here's a rest-specific [usage example](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html#overriding-extra-fields) - rest of the guide should prove usefull as well)

Category model:

```
public function extraFields() {
    return ['subcategories', 'topProducts'];
}
// product relation
public function getTopProducts(){
    return $this->hasMany(Product::className(), ['category_id' => 'id'])
        // ->order()->where() // your criterias
        ->limit(10);
}
// subcategories
public function getChildren(){
    return $this->hasMany(Category::className(), ['id' => 'parent_id']);
}
```

Product model:

```
public function extraFields() {
    return ['iamges'];
}
public function getImages(){
    return $this->hasMany(Image::className(), ['product_id' => 'id'])
}
```

---

ps. since you haven't posed any code or table structure, all relations in my example are based on standard naiming convention